# Flexbox sticky footer extending past the bottom of the page with no content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am implementing a flexbox layout with a sticky footer.  I have a `min-height:100vh` on the `body` and the `.content-container` that holds the content.  I also have a `header` and a `footer` with no height set.  My problem is that the footer is set below the bottom of the page, even with no content.  I've adjusted the `min-height:100vh` to put the footer at the bottom, but then on mobile content extends past the `footer`.  How can I get the `footer` placed at the bottom in all cases?

**The HTML**

```
<header class="page_header">
  <h1>Scoreboard</h1>
</header>

<div class="content_container">
  <main class="content">
    <h2>Visualized Votes</h2>
    <div id="graph_container">

    </div>
  </main>
  <aside class="left_container">
    <h2>Recent Votes</h2>
    <div class="recent_votes_container"></div>
  </aside>
  <aside class="right_container">
    <h2>Top Votes</h2>
    <div class="top_votes_container"></div>
  </aside>
</div>
<footer class="page_footer">
  Awesomeness developed by Mathieu Jonson
</footer>
```

**The CSS**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f6f1ed;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header.page_header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #30231d;
}

header h1 {
  font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

main, aside {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

main h2, aside h2 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background-color: #b5a797;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: .5em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-align: center;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

main p, aside p {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: .5em .5em .3em;
}

footer.page_footer {
  background-color: #6a5750;
  font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.content_container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}

.left_container {
  flex: 1;
  flex: 0 0 15em;
  order: -1;
}

.right_container {
  flex: 0 0 15em;
}

.recent_votes_container, .top_votes_container {
  text-align: center;
}

.recent_votes_container li, .top_votes_container li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .content_container {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1;
  }
  .content_container {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

[The Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/uh0zron4/)
[The Site.](http://developingawesomeness.com/scoreboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the following code. It makes footer's previous sibling too tall, so the footer is pushed too much.

```css
.content_container {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Additionally, the `body` has some margin by default, but `min-height: 100vh` does not include it. Either remove the margin or take it into account.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #f6f1ed;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}
header.page_header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #30231d;
}
header h1 {
  font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
main,
aside {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
main h2,
aside h2 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background-color: #b5a797;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: .5em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-align: center;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}
main p,
aside p {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: .5em .5em .3em;
}
footer.page_footer {
  background-color: #6a5750;
  font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.content_container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}
main {
  flex: 1;
}
.left_container {
  flex: 1;
  flex: 0 0 15em;
  order: -1;
}
.right_container {
  flex: 0 0 15em;
}
.recent_votes_container,
.top_votes_container {
  text-align: center;
}
.recent_votes_container li,
.top_votes_container li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .content_container {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1;
  }
  .content_container {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="page_header">
  <h1>Scoreboard</h1>
</header>

<div class="content_container">
  <main class="content">
    <h2>Visualized Votes</h2>
    <div id="graph_container">

    </div>
  </main>
  <aside class="left_container">
    <h2>Recent Votes</h2>
    <div class="recent_votes_container"></div>
  </aside>
  <aside class="right_container">
    <h2>Top Votes</h2>
    <div class="top_votes_container"></div>
  </aside>
</div>
<footer class="page_footer">
  Awesomeness developed by Mathieu Jonson
</footer>
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius.  The margin was taken care of with a reset, so removing that one line solved it.  Thanks!